# Lower bound on a Fourier series with fractional decay

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, upper-lower-bounds

I'm dealing with a Fourier series which is given as:

$$ f(t,s) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{ \left( \sin( n \pi s) - \sin( n \pi t \right) )^2 }{ n^{2\alpha} } $$

for some $\alpha \in (1/2,1), (s,t) \in [0,1]^2$. Or:

$$ g(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{ \sin^2(n \pi s) }{ n^{2\alpha} } \quad h(s,t) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{ \sin(n \pi s) \sin( n \pi t) }{ n^{2\alpha} }$$

For my purpose, I happen to need a lower bound on $f$ in terms of $t,s$ or $|t-s|$, up to some fractional powers. I have a feeling that it should be more or less standard result, but I don't have a lot of experience in Fourier analysis.

Using interpolation, it is relatively easy to get an upper bound of type $$f(t,s) \leq C |t-s|^{2\beta}$$

for some constant $C$ depending on $\beta,\alpha$, uniform in $t,s$, for $\beta < \alpha-1/2$

Analytical expressions can be obtained for the case $\alpha = 1$, for instance (p. 7):

[https://math.mit.edu/~jerison/103/handouts/brownian.13.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ejerison/103/handouts/brownian.13.pdf)

The expression they get, for $s=0$, is $\sim t^2 - t$, which corresponds to the Holder bound that I obtained - $\alpha = 1, \beta = 1/2$.

I tried to:

1. rewrite it as $\sin(\pi n (t-s)/2) \cos(\pi n (t+s)/2)$ and compare to the infinite integral, to use change of variables and pull $|t-s|$ outside. This would have worked if it wasn't for the factor of $\cos(\pi (t+s)/2)$, which I cannot control from below.
2. expand using square $(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab$, but then I need an upper bound on a product. Then I have:

$$f(t,s) = g^2(t) + g^2(s) - 2h(s,t)$$

For this I need
a) a lower bound on $g$
b) an upper bound on $h$

Maybe I could get something using integral representation, but I need a precise control on constants that appear and it is not very obvious to me that it would work.

Comment: There is a parenthesis problem in the first equation

Comment: indeed it was, thanks